# Discord.js getting shards id

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to get every Shard id by `client.shards.id` but I have this error:

```
(node:3164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PoloIsASkid\bot.js:28:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I have tried `client.shards.Id` too but it didn't work.

How do I fix it? I need it for DBL Stats posting in this command:

```js
dbl.postStats(size, client.shards.id, client.shards.total);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way of getting the Shard ID directly within the Child process. You'll have to send a message from the Main process to the Child process with the Shard ID.

```js
// Creating the Discord.ShardingManager.
const ShardingManager = new Discord.ShardingManager(Path.join(__dirname, "Discord.js"), {
    token: process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN,
    totalShards: 'auto'
});

// Trying to spawn the required shards.
ShardingManager.spawn().catch(error => console.error(`[ERROR/SHARD] Shard failed to spawn.`));

ShardingManager.on("shardCreate", shard => {
    // Listeing for the ready event on shard.
    shard.on("ready", () => {
        console.log(`[DEBUG/SHARD] Shard ${shard.id} connected to Discord's Gateway.`)
        // Sending the data to the shard.
        shard.send({type: "shardId", data: {shardId: shard.id}});
    });
});
```

Now, on the Child process, you need to listen to the "message" event of `process` and grab the Shard ID.

```js
// This is where your Discord bot's code is.
process.on("message", message => {
    if (!message.type) return false;

    if (message.type == "shardId") {
        console.log(`The shard id is: ${message.data.shardId}`);
    };
});
```

---

## Update:

I just found out that you may use [`Guild#shardID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=shardID) and [`Guild#shard`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=shard).
This applies to Discord JS v12.

Example:

```js
message.guild.shardID
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that `client.shards` does not exist, that it is `undefined`. You cannot reference the property of that which does not exist, this is why `client.shards.id` and `client.shards.Id` fails in similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v12, `Client.shard.ids` will be an array of shard IDs being handled by this client ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardClientUtil?scrollTo=ids)).

For a list of all shards from the ShardingManager, the `spawn()` function returns a Promise of a Collection of shards and you can get their IDs from there ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=spawn)).